# How To get Value in AJAX JSON FROM PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

PHP ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type    : "POST",
    data    : dataString,
    url     : "php_proceess_file",
    dataType: "json",
    success : function (JSONObject) {
        var peopleHTML = "";            
        var i = 0;            
        for (var key in JSONObject) {
            if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {           
                pm = JSONObject[key]["pm"];
            }
        }
    }   
});
```

PHP process file:

```
$pm = unserialize($item_row['payment_modes']);    
    array_push($someArray, [    
        'pm' => $pm,    
    ]);
}

// Convert the Array to a JSON String and echo it
$someJSON = json_encode($someArray);
echo $someJSON;
```

I want this type of result single one by one like, how to get nested json value?

```
If (2710000001 != ''){
    Echo 'result'
}
```

Please check image:

[image]

Comment: From the incomplete snippet screenshot, shouldn't that be: `JSONObject["pm"];` ?

Comment: //I want this type of result
If(PM == ‘270000001’
{
 Echo show value
}

Comment: but how to fetch in ajax json value